# Rerun $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a number different functions on different pages that are bound $(document).ready(). I am writing an Ajax login script and want to be able to refresh the page state to reflect the changed login status without reloading the whole page. I'm hoping there's a nice simple way of doing this so I don't restructure all my other scripts.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't re-run `document.ready` as it only fires once per document. If you need this behaviour you should create a separate function which you can call on `document.ready` and then again at any later point to reset the state of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on('ready readyAgain', function() {
    // do stuff
});

// At some other point in time, just trigger readyAgain
$(document).trigger('readyAgain');
```

#### Note:

`$(document).on('ready')` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 according to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  An alternative method is as follows:

```
function myReadyFunction(){}
$(myReadyFunction);

// at some other point, just call your function whenever needed:
myReadyFunction($);
```

Comment: Good minimal-changes idea. You could do `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).trigger('readyAgain'); })` and then `$(document).on("readyAgain", ...);` to avoid the deprecation bit. I didn't want to directly edit such a big change into the answer, but feel free.

Answer (score 2):

Write the code in a separate function and call from all the places you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ///call some function 
});
```

And you can use the same function on ajax success

Comment: This is, of course, the right way to do it (although with what the OP describes, it's more complicated than shown above). With lots of different places binding different code to `ready`, it may be a bigger change than the OP is looking for.